# Permission check logic in Drools using mvel2

Tags: drools, mvel

I am new to drools.How can I resolve this logic properly according to drools syntax (mvel2)??

```
rule CAN_LOGIN_TOACCOUNTMASTER
when 
  c: PermissionCheck( target == "login", action=="can" )
  Role(name in ("A", "B", "C", "D", E", "F"))
c.grant();
```

This syntax is working fine with drools 4 with mvel. but not in drools 5 with mvel2.

**Edit**
The typos are a copy-paste issue.

I received the following the error message in JBOSS EAP 6.3

Caused by: org.drools.rule.InvalidRulePackage: Predicate 'name == "A" || name == "B" || name == "C" || name == "D" || name == "E" || name == "F"' must be a Boolean expression
[Line: 132, Column: 8] : [Rule name='CAN_LOGIN_TOACCOUNTMASTER']

```
at org.drools.rule.Package.checkValidity(Package.java:478) [drools-core-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
at org.drools.common.AbstractRuleBase.addPackages(AbstractRuleBase.java:481) [drools-core-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.addPackages(ReteooRuleBase.java:458) [drools-core-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
at org.drools.reteoo.ReteooRuleBase.addPackage(ReteooRuleBase.java:465) [drools-core-5.3.0.Final.jar:5.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.drools.RuleBase.compileRuleBase(RuleBase.java:121) [jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144) [jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2249) [jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.callCreateMethod(Component.java:2172) [jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar:2.2.0.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2132) [jboss-seam-2.2.0.GA.jar:2.2.0.GA]
... 60 more
```

Comment: I have tried the following, but it's not working.
    Role ((name == "A") || (name == "B") || (name == "C") || (name == "D") || (name == "E") || (name == "F"))

Answer (score 1):

```
rule CAN_LOGIN_TOACCOUNTMASTER
when 
  c: PermissionCheck( target == "login", action=="can" )
  Role(name in ("A", "B", "C", "D", E", "F"))
c.grant();
```

1. There is a quote missing before the `E` in the 4th line.
2. There should be a `then` before the last line, which isn't a pattern.

**Edit** 
Looking at the code throwing the exception, it is to be assumed that you have some error in the code. Since the following rule works OK, with the **assumption** that name is a String field in class Rule, it must the something that is not evident from what you have posted.

Did you check for errors during rule compilation?

If there is a syntax error, indicate *precisely* the Drools version (5 is *not* enough) and add the error message.

**Edit** Correct solutions (all tested and working using 5.3.0) are:

```
when 
c: PermissionCheck( target == "login", action=="can" )
Role(name in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"))
then
```

or

```
when 
c: PermissionCheck( target == "login", action=="can" )
Role(name == "A" || name == "B" || name == "C" || name == "D" ||
     name == "E" || name ==  "F")
then
```

or

```
when 
c: PermissionCheck( target == "login", action=="can" )
Role(name == "A" || == "B" || == "C" ||  == "D" || == "E" || ==  "F")
then
```

Comment: Lanue: Thanks for your help. The above code doesn't work. I have found the answer. I will post it here. It will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved the issue using the following code,

```
rule CAN_LOGIN_TOACCOUNTMASTER
when 
  c: PermissionCheck( target == "login", action=="can" )
  (Role(name == "A") or Role(name == "B") or Role(name == "C") or 
  Role(name == "D") or Role(name == "E") or Role(name == "F"))
  c.grant();
```

Comment: This solution has disadvantages and should not be used as a pattern for tests whether a field matches one out of several values. See the preferred alternatives in my answer.